# gitlab - fatal: repository not found

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to point a folder to a remote gitlab repository and i am getting an error message when having to pass the git pull command. Within a created folder I follow the following steps:

git init

git remote add origin

git remote -v

- the address of the remote repository appears

git pull

fatal: repository  not found

what could be the reason that it is not possible to point to the remote repository?

Comment: Is it possible to clone the remote repository to another folder?

Comment: yes. I can clone the repository

Comment: do you have permission to see that repository?